# How can I fill review icons depending on average rating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up NodeJS and React project. In the project each user has its own listing and each listing has its own reviews. Now I'm getting the review number and then calculating the average review. Now I want to fill icons to whichever average number I recieve. So for example if the average review is 3, 3 stars will be filled and two stars won't be. I made star icon a component and only thing I have to do is `isFilled={true}` to make an icon filled.

How I get average rating number:

```
// Get average number of all ratings
const arrAvg = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
const getAvgRating =
  reviews.length > 0 ? arrAvg(reviews.map(review => review.attributes.rating)) : 0;
const avgRating = parseInt(getAvgRating); // This is my average review number
```

This is my reviews star icons (I want to make each star filled depending on number of average rating):

```
 <IconReviewStar isFilled={true} /> // isFilled will mark icon as filled
 <IconReviewStar isFilled={true} />
 <IconReviewStar isFilled={true} />
 <IconReviewStar />
 <IconReviewStar />
```

Is there any easy workaround for this? So I can save myself of writing unnecessary code. Any help will mean even if its just a article that will point me to the right answer.

Best,
Aleksa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterate and render the prop conditionally to your `avgRating`.

```
const totalFilled = Math.ceil(avgRating);
const totalStars = 5;

const ReviewBar = () =>
  [...Array(totalStars).keys()].map((key) => (
    <IconReviewStar key={key} isFilled={key < totalFilled} />
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If average rating is 3, then using `.map()` function, create `IconReviewStar` components and set `isFilled={true}` as long as index is less than average rating

```
const avgRating = 3;

const iconComponents = [...new Array(5).fill(0)]
        .map((_, i) => <IconReviewStar key={i} isFilled={i < avgRating}/>);
```

`iconComponents` will be an array containing 5 `IconReviewStar` components with 3 of them filled.